# How to make actviity fading transation in android

Tags: android, xml, animation, layout, android-activity

How to make actcity fading in android ?
I used the following code, but nothing happens

```
public class MetroActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.metro_splash);
        getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.anim.intro_anim);
        Runnable r= new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        };
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(r, 3000);


    }
}
```

animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Comment: Bader why you are not using Activity.overridePendingTransition() for fading ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code for  do a smooth fade between two Activities:

**fadein.xml in res/anim:**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="100" />
```

**fadeout.xml in res/anim**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="100" />
```

put the following in the onCreate method for Activity MainActivity. Before setContentView works for me.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

NOTE : if you are using Android2.o or above then overridePendingTransition work

**EDIT:**

or Try after putting this code in MainActivity

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.metro_splash);
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.anim.intro_anim);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation);
    // 'body' is root layout id  which is for MainActivity
    findViewById(R.id.body).startAnimation(anim);
    }
```